# FUSE >= 2.8.4 RPM for CentOS

Tags: centos, repository, fuse, rpm

Is there a known source for CentOS RPMs that provides FUSE version 2.8.4 or later? The latest I can find is 2.7.4 from EPEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find i386 rpm in: http://rpm.vitki.net/pub/centos/5/i386/fuse-2.8.5-99.vitki.01.el5.i386.rpm

the src rpm is in: http://rpm.vitki.net/pub/SRPMS/fuse-2.8.5-99.vitki.01.el5.src.rpm

in case you will need to build it to x86_64...

[a little how to build from source](http://www.mackeldey.de/mainnavi/knowledge_base/knowledge_detail.html?tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=60&tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=8&cHash=9645f65b5bb806f34f332f86df68e3b4)...

Comment: I am quite happy to build from a source RPM, so that's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: sadly those links are now dead